# Terraform: Error in S3 Policy Creation with MalformedPolicy: Policy has invalid resource error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform

```
#Create a s3 bucket policy
resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "jenkins-prj1-cloudstore-policy" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.jenkins-prj1-cloudstore.id

   policy = <<POLICY
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1704624583452",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1704622653819",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::jenkins-prj01-s3bucket/",
                "arn:aws:s3:::jenkins-prj01-s3bucket/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::jenkins-prj01-s3bucket/",
                "arn:aws:s3:::jenkins-prj01-s3bucket/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
POLICY
depends_on = [aws_s3_bucket_public_access_block.override_default_setting]
}
```

from above piece of code I am getting below error now with above resource.

│ Error: putting S3 Bucket (jenkins-prj01-s3bucket) Policy: operation error S3: PutBucketPolicy, https response error StatusCode: 400, RequestID: F5FDY6ABC5D3G4F5, HostID: NhyFijzzU5MIfFWDtiuN7hPGo5qCdQUI1PihUOlDUg2AuLrPXM/MlXjmnlASRPhmx6MsJABpsZw=, api error MalformedPolicy: Policy has invalid resource │ │ with aws_s3_bucket_policy.jenkins-prj1-cloudstore-policy, │ on Main.tf line 73, in resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "jenkins-prj1-cloudstore-policy": │ 73: resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "jenkins-prj1-cloudstore-policy" {

Would like to understand what is the error ?

I am trying to implement a S3 policy via terraform resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" and getting the error as policy has an invalid resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing **Principal** attribute in the second statement. Also bucket should be `arn:aws:s3:::jenkins-prj01-s3bucket`, not `arn:aws:s3:::jenkins-prj01-s3bucket/`.

Comment: Thanks. Now the code works as expected.